# VB ElseIf statements not working

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, conditional-statements

Homework Problem: An Internet service provider offers three subscription packages to its customers, plus
a discount for nonprofit organizations:
a. Package A: 10 hours of access for $9.95 per month. Additional hours are $2.00
per hour.
b. Package B: 20 hours of access for $14.95 per month. Additional hours are
$1.00 per hour.
c. Package C: Unlimited access for $19.95 per month.
d. Nonprofit Organizations: The service provider gives all nonprofit organizations
a 20% discount on all packages.
The user should select the package the customer has purchased (from a set of radio
buttons) and enter the number of hours used. A check box captioned Nonprofit
Organization should also appear on the form. The application should calculate and
display the total amount due. If the user selects the Nonprofit Organization check
box, a 20% discount should be deducted from the final charges. Implementation
note: all rates, limits, and discounts must be declared using symbolic constants
(using the Const keyword).

Use the following data to determine if the application is calculating properly:
Package and Hours The Monthly Charge
Package A, 5 hours, nonprofit $ 7.96
Package A, 25 hours $39.95
Package B, 10 hours, nonprofit $11.96
Package B, 25 hours $19.95
Package C, 18 hours, nonprofit $15.96
Package C, 25 hours $19.95

My Code:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'Declare input and output variables
    Dim intHoursUsed As Integer
    Dim decTotalDue As Decimal

    'Calculate Price if Package A is selected. No discount applied.
    If radPackageA.Checked = True Then
        If intHoursUsed < 10 Then
            decTotalDue = CDec(9.95)
        ElseIf intHoursUsed > 10 Then
            decTotalDue = CDec((9.95) + ((intHoursUsed - 20) * 2))
        End If
    End If

    'Calculate Price if Package B is selected. No discount applied.
    If radPackageB.Checked = True Then
        If intHoursUsed <= 20 Then
            decTotalDue = CDec(14.95)
        ElseIf intHoursUsed > 20 Then
            decTotalDue = CDec((14.95) + ((intHoursUsed - 20) * 1))
        End If
    End If

    'Calculate Price if Package C is selected. No discount applied.
    If radPackageC.Checked = True Then
        decTotalDue = CDec(19.95)
    End If

    'Declare named constant for Nonprofit Discount rate (0.8)
    Const Nonprofit As Decimal = CDec(0.8)

    'Add and calculate discount if checkbox is checked.
    If chkNonprofit.Checked = True Then
        decTotalDue = CDec(decTotalDue * Nonprofit)
    End If

    'Display Total Amount Due in label as string in currency format
    lblTotalDue.Text = decTotalDue.ToString("c")

    'Display Error Message it Hours exceed 744
    If CInt(txtHoursUsed.Text) > 744 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please try again. Value must be a numeric inter and must not exceed 744.")
        txtHoursUsed.Clear()
        lblTotalDue.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I calculate for Package A and B, the answer is just $9.95 and 14.95, no matter how many hours it is. Please Help! Im so frustrated. I cant find what is wrong (Im a noob).

Comment: Can you format your code a little? It's not very easy to read. Also welcome to [so], please take a [tour]!

Comment: Where did you **assign value** to `intHoursUsed` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you got from your program makes perfect sense if, apparently, you didn't assign value to `intHoursUsed` variable anywhere :

```
Dim intHoursUsed As Integer = CInt(txtHoursUsed.Text)
......
```

In that case, `intHoursUsed` value default to 0, then `intHoursUsed < 10` and `intHoursUsed <= 20` are always true. This way, as you stated, the answer will always be $9.95 and 14.95, no matter how many hours it is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be revealed by formatting, as Unihedron suggests above.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
'Declare input and output variables
Dim intHoursUsed As Integer
Dim decTotalDue As Decimal

'Get the total hours
intHoursUsed = CInt(txtHoursUsed.Text)

'Calculate Price if Package A is selected. No discount applied.
If radPackageA.Checked = True Then
    If intHoursUsed <= 10 Then
        decTotalDue = CDec(9.95)
    ElseIf intHoursUsed > 10 Then
        decTotalDue = CDec((9.95) + ((intHoursUsed - 20) * 2))
    End If
/* Missing End If here */

    'Calculate Price if Package B is selected. No discount applied.
    If radPackageB.Checked = True Then
        If intHoursUsed <= 20 Then
            decTotalDue = CDec(14.95)
        ElseIf intHoursUsed > 20 Then
            decTotalDue = CDec((14.95) + ((intHoursUsed - 20) * 1))
        End If
    End If
/*Rest omitted for brevity */
```

The missing `End If` makes everything filter through the first check, `radPackageA.Checked = True`. If this is NOT true, then none of the code beyond this gets looked at. Proper code formatting probably would have helped you find this more quickly, and people reading your code will appreciate it a lot, as well.

Comment: `If radPackageA.Checked = True Then` can be reduced to `If radPackageA.Checked Then`

Comment: okay, I did what you said but i still have the same problem. It is like it is ignoring the Elseif statements. I even tried other codes that i found online such as: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/49023-help-with-assignment/ and still the same problem. when i click calculate no matter what number of hours i enter, it gives me &9.95 for A and $14.95 for B

Comment: You need to assign something to <code>intHoursUsed</code>. Currently, if this is the totality of your code, you are missing that, too. See my edits above.